# Is it possible to create comparators based on a dynamic type?

Tags: java, types, comparator

I have been trying to create a comparator through a field of an object, and I can't seem to be able to morph the comparator's type to what I want.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class Sort {

private ArrayList list;
public Class<?> type;
private Object obj = "Continent";

Sort(ArrayList list, String type) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    this.list = list;
    this.type = Class.forName(type);

}
Comparator a = new Comparator<this.type>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(b.area o1, b.area o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

};
```

is it possible or would I need to write out the methods for each individual class case?

Comment: Can you explain the larger problem here? What you're trying to do won't work, but it's unclear why you need to do this.

Comment: Comparator is Interface so how can you make the object here..

Comment: @Neuron By creating an anonymous class of that interface type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part I

> is it possible [...]?

Not the way you're trying it. You're confusing compile time and run time, i.e.:

- Generics are a pure compile time concept in Java. In fact, the generic type is removed during compilation (that's called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). It only exists to give you type safety before compilation, meaning while *writing* your code.
- But the instance `type` is only assigned at run time. And because you don't know its type during compile time, you had to use a [wildcard generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) for it. So you only know the type, when you're *executing* your code.

So you can see that you can't use the information you gathered while *executing* your code to help you *write* it.

I highly recommend you read Oracle's [tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

## Part II

> would I need to write out the methods for each individual class case?

I'm with Paul on this. I'm sure we can help you but you should give us an idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

...

Based on on your comment, I think the following would be a good solution.

Your model of the reality consists of continents, countries and cities. Hence you should have classes `Continent`, `Country` and `City`. Since you're modeling population, all of them should have a method `getPopulation()`. And this is one thing they have in common; all of those things are populated. The way to address this common structure / behavior in Java is to create an interface (let's call it `Populated`) with a method `getPopulation()` and have all of those classes implement it:

```
public interface Populated {

    int getPopulation();

}

public class Country implements Populated {

    @Override
    public int getPopulation() {
        ...
    }

}

// same for Continent and City
```

Now you have three classes but they can all be treated as one thing, as being populated. For example you can collect them in a list:

```
List<Populated> populated = new ArrayList<>();
populated.add(new Country());
populated.add(new City());
...
```

And this list can be sorted with a comparator which works for instances of `Populated`:

```
public class PopulationComparator implements Comparator<Populated> {

    public int compare(Populated left, Populated right) {
        return left.getPopulation() - right.getPopultion();
    }

}
```

Comment: well basically I'm trying to compare several different objects using the same mechanisms as a tool to sort the list Collections.sort.The objects are such as the population of a country, city, and continent. I was trying to write a method that could take in country.population or city.population depending on what data the user chose to be sorted and printed.